# Returning a values if a variable is in a column field in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a dataset that uses numpy and pandas and I made a variable that has all the categories of  employees by manager, consultant and assistant. All IDs are in a column **ID** and position is **Pos_ID**. What I want is to have a code that allows me to make a new column that returns if they are a manager or not.
Example of what I have:

```
ID    Job_Title      Pos_ID
101   Consultant     11013
102   Manager        11014
103   Manager        11015
104   Assistant      11016
105   Consultant     11017
106   Manager        11018
```

Here is what I need:

```
ID    Job_Title     Pos_ID     Emp_Type
101   Consultant    11013         C
102   Manager       11014         M
103   Manager       11015         M
104   Assistant     11016         A
105   Consultant    11017         C
106   Manager       11018         M
```

I have tried using:

```
manager = 11014,11015,11018,11024
consult = 11013, 11017
ast = 11016,11027

Emp_Type = []
for code in df['Pos_ID']
   if manager == code:
        Emp_Type.append('M')
   elif consult == code:
        Emp_Type.append('C')
   else:
        Emp_Type.append('A')
df['Emp_Type'] = Emp_Type
```

When I do this all results turn to 'A' I just have no clue why. The dataset has about 5000+ IDs so I have a lot more pos_ids then this.

Comment: "When I do this all results turn to 'A' I just have no clue why" - `manager` and `consult` are tuples, so they won't be equal to any individual value in `df['Pos_ID']`. So the `if` and `elif` conditions will always be false, and the code will fall through to the `else` clause.

Comment: so what would be the best way to go about seeing if a tuple's values are in a column or not?

Comment: the minimal change to your current code would be to do `if code in manager` and `if code in consult`. You could also do something more Pandas-native using the `isin` method, and avoid a `for` loop over the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rely on the first letter of `Job_Title` :

```
df['Emp_Type'] = df['Job_Title'].str[0]
```

---

```
    ID   Job_Title  Pos_ID Emp_Type
0  101  Consultant   11013        C
1  102     Manager   11014        M
2  103     Manager   11015        M
3  104   Assistant   11016        A
4  105  Consultant   11017        C
5  106     Manager   11018        M
```